# Is $x^3$ really an increasing function for all intervals?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, real-numbers, applications

I had an argument with my maths teacher today...
He says, along with another classmate of mine that $x^3$ is increasing for all intervals. I argue that it isn't.
If we look at conditions for increasing, decreasing and stable states of a function,
for a function $f(x)$:

function is increasing for $f'(x) > 0$

function is decreasing for $f'(x) < 0$

(as per my knowledge) function is neither increasing nor decreasing (i.e. it's stable) for $f'(x) = 0$

**so for $x = 0$, function $f(x) = x^3$ should be stable, NOT INCREASING. Hence the interval for which the function must be increasing, according to me, would be $\mathbb{R}$ - {$0$}.**

This means, the function $f(x)=x^3$ should be increasing for all real values EXCEPT $x=0$.

My teacher denied, saying that we consider values of $f'(x) >= 0$.
My response was to look at the function $f(x) = x^2$ which is increasing for interval $(0, \infty]$ and decreasing for interval $(\infty, 0]$, without a doubt.

again, I reason that this time too, $x=0$ is neither decreasing nor increasing hence it is not included in either of the intervals. My teacher, had nothing to say on this, simply telling me that these two examples are completely incomparable.

[another reasoning that my classmate and my teacher gave was that $x=0$ is a single point. Thus the function has to be constant there. Since the function is increasing before and after the point $x=0$, the function must be increasing for value $x=0$ as well.

In my opinion, that is completely against the very idea of calculus. When we define the rate of change at a point, it is solely attributed to that point alone. The limit of the rate of change, as points around $x=0$ close in on 0 is 0, hence in my opinion, the function should be constant at $x=0$, while increasing elsewhere in the set of real numbers]

Am I correct?

Comment: Your teacher and classmate are right, and the explanation of the latter (between square parentheses) is correct up to the point where he says the function's constant in that point, which makes no sense. Another way to put it in a simple way: zero is not an extreme value, but it is an inflection point. Yet the very discussion of whether a function is increasing or not *at a single point* seems to be rather pointless, imo.

Comment: The key here is that you are interested in the function's behavior on intervals, but only looking at derivative information at a single point. Positive derivative at a point does not imply that the function is increasing in any interval containing that point. For the canonical example, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4315614/can-a-function-have-a-positive-derivative-at-a-point-but-not-be-increasing-decre

Comment: Another way to think about it is as follows: if you take a tiny step in the positive direction at ${x=0}$, say ${h}$, is ${f(x+h) > f(x)}$? And the answer is yes: ${(x+h)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2h + 3xh^2 + h^3 > x^3}$. When it comes to asking if a function is increasing or decreasing, the definition is not based on derivatives. It's just that it's possible to use derivatives to aid you in figuring out if a function is increasing or decreasing on a particular interval (for example, if a function has ${f'(x) > 0}$ all across an interval, you can conclude it's increasing on that interval)

Comment: if you are right, you must find an interval (a,b) where $a\neq b$ such that $ f(a) \ge f(b) $.

Comment: Just a note to add on to the many correct answers you've already gotten: People do use the phrase "increasing at point X", but it's always a loose phrase, it's not always reliable, and always needs to take a back seat to the rigorous two-point definition.

Comment: @MetehanTuran

here is one:
Lim h->0 (x-h, x+h)

I see everyone's point here... but well everyone says increasing or decreasing has got nothing to do with calculus.

That means increase or decrease are unrelated to rates of change? huh?

My point is that calculus, in itself, has the essence of capturing information about what a function does (in terms of change) at intervals around a specific point. If everyone else is in fact correct, which I'm beginning to guess they are, my only question then is, why don't we include 0 within the intervals for $f(x) = x^2$? It would satisfy both.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose, in the essence of calculus, it is! That is what my point is precisely about. For a limit of values closer and closer to 0, they will be equal. Well okay, that might be wrong, I see you do have a point there... no matter how small, there is a difference. But that means including the 0 for increasing as well as decreasing intervals for $f(x) = x^2$ would be just fine. Why don't we do it then?

Comment: I mean come onnnnn just agree that AT x=0, the function isn't increasing, i.e the rate of change at its infinitesimal proximity IS INDEED 0.

Comment: We're getting a bit fuzzy here, but "calculus ... has the essence of capturing information about what a function does..... at intervals around a specific point" is where I think you're going wrong. Calculus tells you what's left when the interval shrinks away to nothing. (I'm speaking very loosely there, practically poetically.) And increasing/decreasing, strictly, describes behavior over an interval. There are theorems that connect the two (sometimes), but they are different things.

Comment: @Maddy I have to agree with JonathanZ here and say we are getting fuzzy with words here. What exactly does it mean to say the function isn't increasing **at a single point**? If you want to talk about whether a function is increasing or decreasing on an interval, you need to consider it's behaviour over that entire interval. If you consider the behaviour of ${x^3}$ over the whole real line (i.e. the interval ${(-\infty,\infty)}$), then it is in fact increasing, in the precise sense that if ${a < b}$ then ${f(a) < f(b)}$

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help and clarification. I see I've been quite stubborn with my thoughts but well, I'm still learning and am still just a kid I guess. [xD Sorry, just had a crazy thought at night so well here goes (I do realise I'm wrong): *we MIGHT define increase as if imagining a car moving up a ramp with zero friction. for each height it gains, it has to accelerate. say $f(x) = x^3$ is what defines the ramp. I guess it is obvious that there comes a single instance at $x=0$ for which the car would NOT have to accelerate. This is what I mean by zero slope and no increase.* huh?]

Comment: @Maddy one final thought on your last comment - it is fine to say the slope (of the tangent line) for $x^3$ is $0$ at that individual point. It’s equally fine to say the rate of change is equal to $0$ at that point.  Those are both “infinitesimal” concepts for lack of a better word.  Increasing, on the other hand, is what I would call a local concept (and sometimes a global one as well), meaning it describes behavior over a range of inputs.  I won’t digress further on the exact meaning of these words but as you move forward in mathematics it will help to keep in mind this kind of distinction.

Comment: @MW, got it! infinitesimal, local and global scopes... the infinitesimal information is what is determined using the local and global scopes. The local and global scopes are NOT determined using the infinitesimal, as far as the formal 'increasing' definition goes. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When we say $f$ is increasing over an interval $I$, we are not making a statement about $f’$ at all, we are making a statement about $f$, namely that for $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$ we have $f(a)<f(b)$.

Since this is true for all intervals for the function $f(x)=x^3$, we say the function is increasing on all intervals.

Note this definition applies for functions that are not even differentiable everywhere, so we certainly don’t need or want to use the derivative in our definition of when a function is increasing.

##### Remark

A $C^1$ function (i.e., one with a continuous derivative) satisfying $f’(a)>0$ *will* be guaranteed to be increasing on some interval containing $a$, but as your example of $x^3$ shows, the converse is not necessarily true.

##### Update

Having seen the discussion in the comments, I'm gathering that you have something of a philosophical objection to the above characterization of "increasing", and would prefer an infinitesimal definition based on the derivative, as more in keeping with "the very idea of calculus", as you put it in the main post.

The definition of "increasing" I've given is essentially standard (some would add the modifier "strictly" for clarity), but based on your concerns, let me also offer a sort of philosophical justification for why we define things the way we do.

While infinitesimal concepts (like the derivative) are certainly an important part of calculus, a perhaps even more important part of the subject concerns the relationship between infinitesimal information, and local and global behavior of a function.

This is famously seen in the fundamental theorem of calculus, which relates the infinitesimal rate of change with the global change over an interval, but is also seen in statements like "If $f$ has a local extremum at $x$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f'(x)=0$" (note that the reverse is not true, as the example of $x^3$ shows).

In other words, while we obtain infinitesimal information from the derivative, we are often doing so not for its own sake, but rather in order to answer questions that are not about infinitesimal behavior, but instead about local and global behavior of a function.  And whether $f$ is increasing or not is one such question.

##### Final clarification

[upgraded from comments since it relates to the original question]

I see near the end of your post you mentioned the example of $f(x)=x^2$.  Here there is a subtle distinction at play.  It is true that $f$ is increasing over $[0,\infty)$.  However, when we say $f$ is increasing at a point, that's usually shorthand for "increasing over some open interval containing that point."

This creates two slightly different questions:

1. What's the largest interval over which $f$ is increasing? (answer: $[0,\infty)$).
2. What's the set of points at which $f$ is increasing? (answer: $(0,\infty)$).

However, the first question doesn't always have a well defined answer - consider something like $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$, which is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and on $[1,\infty)$, but not over the union of those intervals, (since $f(1)<f(0)$), so which interval would you pick to be the answer?
Therefore, usually we ask the second question instead (in this final example the answer would  be $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$).

Comment: that... is pretty convincing. Here's what I've understood from this nice, detailed answer of yours as well as those of others, including those in the comments... 'Increasing' can have different meanings. But generally speaking, it is defined as the following: function f(x) is said to be increasing $<=> x<y => f(x) < f(y)$ for some interval. For $f(x)=x^3$, even though there appears to be a slope of 0 for $x=0$, it's increasing for any set of 2 distinct points. Although the infinitesimal information is useful, it doesn't entirely determine the global scope, in fact, the other way around is true

Comment: Just one last bit of question, what you mean is that intervals over which $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing and decreasing BOTH INCLUDE $0$? since $0$ would satisfy the formal definition in either case. So its like the function decreasing from $(-\infty, 0]$ and increasing from  $[0, \infty)$ ??? xD well that again comes down to huh... $0$ is again neither of those. But I see your point ig... it's that 0 is not included when we say 'over an interval' yeah?

Comment: @Maddy Well, you could include $0$ if you just want to say it’s increasing “over” $[0,\infty)$.   What you wouldn’t do is say it’s increasing “at” $0$, because there’s no open interval containing $0$ where it’s increasing.  (The reasons why we often require behavior on specifically *open* intervals vs closed intervals, or in some cases vice versa, would lead to a huge digression on topology which might have to wait for another time, alas.)

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Okay, i know I said that was the last one but well, please read my last comment on the question.

Comment: I read this whole Q&A several hours after the fact and it's been quite a journey. Congratulations to everybody involved.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is correct. For a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be *strictly increasing*, we need $x<y$ to imply $f(x)<f(y)$. So let's see if this is the case for $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x^3$.

If I understand you correctly, you are convinced that we have $f(x)<f(y)$ whenever $x<y<0$ and whenever $0<x<y$. So let us look at the other cases.

Firstly, if $x<0\leq y$, then $f(x)<0\leq f(y)$, and so in particular $f(x)<f(y)$. If $x\leq 0< y$, then $f(x)\leq 0<f(y)$, and so again, $f(x)<f(y)$.

In total, we end up with what we want: $f$ is indeed strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$.

---

What you might want to keep in mind is the following: if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, except for finitely many $x$ for which we have $f'(x)=0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$. The proof of this statement is similar to our above discussion.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, this comes down to how you're going to define your terms.  I would argue that the meaning of ‘increasing’ and ‘decreasing’ doesn't depend on Caclulus; we can explain it with a few inequalities, and even use it in contexts where we're not talking about anything like real numbers (so that Calculus doesn't even make sense there).  I use the following four definitions:

- A function $ f $ is **strictly increasing** on a set $ S $ if, whenever $ x $ and $ y $ are in $ S $ and $ x < y $, then $ f ( x ) $ and $ f ( y ) $ exist and $ f ( x ) < f ( y ) $;
- A function $ f $ is **weakly increasing** on a set $ S $ if, whenever $ x $ and $ y $ are in $ S $ and $ x \leq y $, then $ f ( x ) $ and $ f ( y ) $ exist and $ f ( x ) \leq f ( y ) $;
- A function $ f $ is **strictly decreasing** on a set $ S $ if, whenever $ x $ and $ y $ are in $ S $ and $ x < y $, then $ f ( x ) $ and $ f ( y ) $ exist and $ f ( x ) > f ( y ) $;
- A function $ f $ is **weakly decreasing** on a set $ S $ if, whenever $ x $ and $ y $ are in $ S $ and $ x \leq y $, then $ f ( x ) $ and $ f ( y ) $ exist and $ f ( x ) \geq f ( y ) $.

Depending on context, one usually takes either ‘strictly’ or ‘weakly’ as the default, so that one of these adverbs doesn't need to be said; in your class, I think that you'd take ‘strictly’ as the default.

Notice that by these definitions, it makes no sense to say that a function is increasing *at* a point, only *on* a set (which is typically an open interval in Calculus).

Now when $ f $ is real-valued and $ S $ is an interval in the real line, we have these theorems:

1. If $ f $ is differentiable on $ S $ with $ f ' ( x ) > 0 $ for each $ x \in S $, then $ f $ must be strictly increasing on $ S $;
2. If $ f $ is differentiable on $ S $, then $ f $ is weakly increasing on $ S $ if and only if $ f ' ( x ) \geq 0 $ for each $ x \in S $;
3. If $ f $ is differentiable on $ S $ with $ f ' ( x ) < 0 $ for each $ x \in S $, then $ f $ must be strictly decreasing on $ S $;
4. If $ f $ is differentiable on $ S $, then $ f $ is weakly decreasing on $ S $ if and only if $ f ' ( x ) \leq 0 $ for each $ x \in S $.

(These can all be proved using the Mean-Value Theorem.)

Notice that theorems (1) and (3) are weaker than theorems (2) and (4); they have missing converses that are not true, as you can see from the examples $ x \mapsto x ^ 3 $ and $ x \mapsto - x ^ 3 $.

Now, if you want to define a notion of whether a function $ f $ is strictly/weakly increasing/decreasing at a point $ x $, then you might think, at least if you restrict yourself to differentiable functions, of just looking at $ f ' ( x ) $.  Then you'd define increasing/decreasing on a set to mean increasing/decreasing at every point in that set.  But because theorems (1) and (3) lack these converses, that would mean changing the definition.  I can't *prove* to you that this is wrong, since definitions vary (such as whether to take the strict or weak version as the default).  But the bottom line is that your class seems to be using the same definitions as I am (at least the ‘strictly’ ones).

Comment: Do you mean to say even a floor(x) function, which is evidently constant at certain intervals is a 'weakly' increasing function?

Comment: That's right.  Sometimes people say ‘non-decreasing’ instead.  Weakly increasing functions are more commonly studied in Order Theory, where they're also known as ‘monotone’ or ‘monotone increasing’.  But in the context of Calculus, I'd take ‘increasing’ to mean ‘strictly increasing’ by default, and of course the floor function is not strictly increasing on any nontrivial interval.

Comment: (My main reason for mentioning the weak concepts at all is for the contrast; you get the converse of the theorems for them, but not for the strict concepts.  But your question is only about the strict concepts.)

Answer (score 2):

Let me point out a few things without using the "inc..." word.

I'll assume throughout that $f$ is a real valued function defined on an open subinterval $I$ of the real numbers.

Here is a true statement:

> (1) If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $I$, then $x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in $I$.

This statement is proved in 1st semester calculus by applying the Mean Value Theorem, as I'm sure you know.

The converse of statement (1) is the following false statement:

> (2) If $x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in $I$, then $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $I$.

This statement is false because $f(x)=x^3$ is a counterexample.

I'm sure you agree with me so far.

---

Now we come to a question of linguistics. The following property of the function $f$ on the interval $I$ occurs in both statements (1) and (2), namely:

> $x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in $I$.

What terminology shall we adopt to refer to this property in shorthand?

One standard terminology for this property that is adopted by mathematicians is this (and here comes the "inc..." word):

> $f$ is increasing on $I$.

There are variants on this. For instance some might insist that we instead say *$f$ is strictly increasing on $I$*.

And one can certainly have a debate, on a linguistic/philosophical level regarding whether this choice of terminology is appropriate. For example, if one objected to this terminology on the grounds that it is not an accurate description of infinitesmal behavior.... well, perhaps there is a different terminology that you could convince the global mathematical community to adopt (good luck with that).

But what is not up for debate is that (1) is true and (2) is false, because one can *prove* that (1) is true and (2) is false.

And one thing you can't stop mathematicians from doing is to adopt terminology to refer to mathematical properties in shorthand. Is the terminology always perfect? Do our natural language terms always model exactly all the mathematical subtleties? No. Mathematics and natural language are not always an exact match, so we do the best that we can.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add: a differentiable function $f\colon I\to\mathbb R$ from an interval $I$ to the reals is strictly increasing if and only if $f'(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in I$ and there is no interval $J\subseteq I$ (of positive length) such that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in J$ (i.e., the set of points with $f'(x)>0$ is dense in $I$).

Answer (score 0):

In all points other than $x = 0$ $f(x) = x^3$ is clearly increasing because $f’(x) = 3x^2 > 0$

For $x = 0$, you compare $f(x)$ with $f(y)$ for any $y > 0 = x$, and $f(y) > 0 = f(x)$. And you compare with $f(y)$ for any $y < 0 = x$, and $f(y) < 0 = f(x)$. So $f$ is increasing at $x = 0$.

You were misled by $f’(x) = 0$. Once in a while you have a function where this happens because $f(x)$ is constant around $x$. Quite often it happens because f has a maximum or minimum at $x$, so $f$ is increasing up to $x$ and decreasing from $x$ onward. And once in a while you have a function like $x^3$ where $f’(x) = f’’(x) = 0.$